# Failed to update SP D 2013 with KB 3114337

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, kb-update

I am trying to apply SharePoint Designer KB3114337 on my desktop, but it fails to install.

What's wrong with my system ? I am already having SharePoint Designer 2013 installed on my desktop

[image: SPD2013-KB-updatefailed]

Comment: The update file seems to be for 64-bit Office, do you have that or the 32-bit version?

Comment: Yes, my desktop is ,x64 bit h/w & my ms office 2013 proff+ is also of 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid checking the package detection as the following

- Open CMD as Administrator.
- Navigate to the update folder using Tab then add the following attribute after update file name as the following:

> C:\ .\updatefolder\update.exe PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1

[image]

For more details check [The expected version of the product was not found on the system during install a cumulative update in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/06/14/the-expected-version-of-the-product-was-not-found-on-the-system-during-install-a-cumulative-update-in-sharepoint-2013/)

**[Update]**

Make sure that [Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013
 Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817441/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1) has been installed before applying the update **[KB3114337](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114337/january-12,-2016,-update-for-sharepoint-designer-2013-kb3114337)** for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013.

Comment: unfortunately your suggestions didnt work, m.qassas !

Comment: @SaMolPP Sorry to hear that, please check my updated answer. hope it help you.